# Can't install .apk after decoding and rebuild (Apktool, Apkstudio)

Tags: android, apk, decode

I decoded an apk file with *apktool* and I didn't change anything. After that I just build it again and then I tried to install the apk but i got the below error even after some basic change.

What I did using windows `cmd`:

```
apktool d somename.apk -o testfolder
```

then

```
apktool b testfolder
```

and:

```
adb install somename.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/somename.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
```

I did it with apkstudio and the result was the same.

```
$ adb install -r "somename.apk"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/somename.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
Process exited with code 0
```

> Was it a system app? No.

Can someone help me about it?

Comment: did you decompile an app that you made yourself?

Comment: yes. it was my old app and i don't have access to the source anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-system apks need to be signed after recompiling. 
Try to sign your apk: [Signing Your App Manually](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually)

Answer (score 7):

I Know it was answered before but for more clarification , you can sign it by these commands.

First Generate the Key :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Second sign it :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

IF you Don't like to enter a password after previous command or do it in bash file, use this :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [Your Key Store] [Address/YourApk.apk] alias_name  -storepass [Your Password]
```

Comment: In earlier versions of android a new signature scheme, V2 was made and this one instead of signing only the jar files it signs the whole apk so you might get an error telling you that something is wrong with the signing so you should you apksigner