# Cannot install an app that was recompiled with apktool?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I decompiled an app using apktool and without modifying it I recompiled it again.When I tried to install the produced apk into my phone,there was error massage "xApplication not installed".

Comment: Did you resign it with the original key?

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099474/cant-install-apk-after-decoding-and-rebuild-apktool-apkstudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After building the app, you have to sign the apk in order to install it on your device. You can use testsign.jar.
You should also always check adb installation log to figure out what gone wrong.